# Terms and condition on add to cart

Tags: addtocart, terms-and-conditions

I'm looking for a way to add the ability to enforce an end user to acknowledge a **policy** before they **purchase specific items** in the store.

I'd prefer it happen when the item is **added to the cart**. What is the best way to get that done? I'm relatively new to Magento, and I have searched existing **add-ons**, but am having no luck coming up with a solution.

Comment: https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/sales/terms-conditions.html - For Magento1


https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/sales/terms-and-conditions.html - For magento2

Comment: Which version of magento you are using ?

Comment: magento 2.2 - also to clarify, I don't want terms and conditions to show up for all items. Only if a specific category of item is in the cart.

Answer (score 0):

First ->
Step 1: Login to your Magento Admin Panel, go to Stores->Terms and Conditions
Step 2: Click On "Add New Condition" button
Step 3: Fill all necessary information for your new Condition. Don’t forget to change the Status to Enable options and then click Save Condition


Second->
Step 1: go to Stores->Configuration->SALES->Checkout->Enable Terms and Conditions->yes
Step 2 : click on "Save Config" button

Comment: On the checkout page, customers can read your terms and conditions. before place order.

Comment: Please check this url
http://www.venustheme.com/create-magento-2-terms-and-conditions/

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I recognize now that I didn't clarify well enough. I need the terms and conditions to only shop up for a specific category of items. It can happen on checkout or addtocart, but I don't want it to happen at all if they don't purchase from the specific category.

Comment: Please read this
https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/catalog/category-product-rules.html